# Titanium - ProxyFactory: failed to find class for ti.modules.titanium.network.HTTPClientProxy

Tags: android, titanium, titanium-mobile, android-bluetooth, titanium-modules

I have a Titanium Android application for iBeacons detections, the app runs on background service and when that detects an iBeacon the app makes a HTTP request using Titanium.Network.HTTPClient.

Sometimes the service stops and shows the dialog stopped Android message for my app. Checking the log from "adb logcat" i get this feedback:

```
I/TiAPI   (29207):  => fetchAdByBeacon
E/JNIUtil (29207): ProxyFactory: failed to find class for ti.modules.titanium.network.HTTPClientProxy
E/ProxyFactory(29207): No proxy info found for class.
F/libc    (29207): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 29229 (KrollRuntimeThr)
```

I think it could be a problem on Titanium Proxy when this is trying to get a new HTTPClient native object, but my question is... Could i handle this Titanium exception and prevent the app closes?

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing a similar problem. What I noticed is that the entire device (Nexus 7, Android 4.4.2) didn't have a network connection (i.e. I couldn't browse the Internet with the Chrome browser, even though I seemed to be be connected to my usual wireless network).

I don't know yet what might have caused the problem, but rebooting my device solved it for me. You might want to verify that you have network connectivity.